# How come 'current_spree_user' is available in the views, while it is not an instance variable

Tags: spree, solidus

I'm using Solidus/Spree.

Normally when you use variables from the controller, you use instance variables that start with an `@`.

In my views, I have seen the use of `current_spree_user` which is not an instance variable, but it does work. I don't see this local variable 'current_spree_user' being assigned somewhere in my view.

Anybody knows how it is possible that `current_spree_user` is an valid variable within a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an controller instance variable, but controller helper method :
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/lib/spree/authentication_helpers.rb